# Solve with only one query?

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE list(
country TINYINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
name VARCHAR(10) CHARACTER SET latin1 NOT NULL,
name_index INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
UNIQUE KEY(country, name), PRIMARY KEY(country, name_index)) ENGINE = INNODB
```

I want to:

Given: `($country, $name, $new_index)`

1. Check if a row with `country = $country && name = $name` exists.
2. If the row exists, get the index `$index = name_index`.
3. If the row doesn't exist, add it and then get the index.

I can do the following using many queries, but I am looking for an efficient way to do it, using only one query. Is this possible?

Comment: I don't think you can INSERT and SELECT in the same query.

Comment: you will need to write a stored procedure for this.

Comment: What's a stored procedure?

Comment: it's easier to do it in PHP (faster to)

Comment: @bkdude I wonder how it would be faster in PHP. Would PHP bypass the DBMS and write directly to database disk files?

Comment: @We'reAllMadHere In the (3rd) case, when the row doesn't exist, what value should be used for the `name_index` column?

Comment: @We'reAllMadHere - http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.stored-procedures.php

Comment: @ypercube: it will be given, as `$new_index`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible with only one query.

You CAN do this:

```
$sql = "SELECT name_index FROM (your table) WHERE country = '$country' AND
name = '$name' LIMIT 1";
$query = mysql_query($sql);
$numrows = mysql_num_rows($query);
if($numrows == 1) {
   $row = mysql_fetch_row($query);
   $index = $row[0];
} else {
   $sql = "INSERT INTO (your table) (country, name)
   VALUES('$country','$name')";
   $query = mysql_query($sql);
   $check = mysql_num_rows($query);
   if($check > 0) {
      $sql = "SELECT name_index FROM (your table) WHERE country = '$country' AND
      name = '$name' LIMIT 1";
      $query = mysql_query($sql);
      $row = mysql_fetch_row($query);
      $index = $row[0];
   } else {
      echo "Error occured while trying to insert new row";
   }
}
```

Hope this helps :).

Comment: Why would the `mysql_insert_id()` return the `name_index` value?

Comment: well, it's a build-in php function if I'm not mistaking, It will return the latest ID added. See this [link](http://nl3.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-insert-id.php)

Comment: Exactly, it says *"Retrieves the ID generated for an AUTO_INCREMENT column by the previous query (usually INSERT)."* I see no `AUTO_INCREMENT` attribute for the `name_index` column.

Comment: yea you're right there, I'll edit my post in a sec. :)